# ReactJS sorting column with dynamic class creation

Tags: reactjs, sorting

I've inherited a large pile of code and it generally works. This is running on v0.13.3.

The problem I am having is in sorting columns. Whenever I invoke the handler for the click event below, I am getting a null `this.state`. I must be missing something simple because I have done a lot of stare/compare vs other working code and I just don't see it but this example component is hassling me.

I've simplified down to just the problem component as a standalone html file with static sample data:

```
<div id="content">Loading ...</div>
<script>
var theData = [{"id":"47483648","labName":"Lab0"},{"id":"47483650","labName":"Lab1"},{"id":"47483651","labName":"Lab2"},{"id":"47483654","labName":"Lab3"}];

function render() {
  React.render(React.createElement(aTable, {data: theData}),document.getElementById("content"));
}

var aTable = React.createClass({displayName: "aTable",
  handleHeaderClick: function(sortBy) {
      console.log("firing aTable handleHeaderClick");
      //this.state is null here
      var newState = this.state;

      if (this.state.sortBy === sortBy && this.state.sortOrder === 'asc') {
          newState.sortOrder = 'desc';
      }
      else {
          newState.sortOrder ='asc';
      }
      newState.sortBy = sortBy;

      this.setState(newState);
  },
  render: function(){
      var theItems = $.map(this.props.data, function (key, value) {
          console.log("the items", key);
          return (
              React.createElement("tr",{key: key.id + "-row"}, 
                  React.createElement("td", {key: key.agentid}, key.id),
                  React.createElement("td", {key: key.labName}, key.labName),
              )
          );
      });

      return (
          React.createElement("div", {id: "holder"},  
              React.createElement("div", {id: "a-table"}, 
                  React.createElement("table",null,
                      React.createElement("thead",null,
                          React.createElement("tr",null,
                              React.createElement("th",null," The ID"),
                              React.createElement("th",
                                  {onClick: this.handleHeaderClick.bind(this, "labName")},
                                  "Lab Name")
                              )
                          ),
                      React.createElement("tbody",null,
                          theItems
                      )
                  )
              )
          )
      );
  }
});


$(document).ready(function () {

  render();
});
```

This throws up an exception on the null state:

```
basic.html:37 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sortBy' of null
```

Which refers to this line:

```
if (this.state.sortBy === sortBy && this.state.sortOrder === 'asc') {
```

I have latitude to change the handler logic, but am stuck with this pattern for the time being.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1**
This is a working fiddle where I worked out the sorting by doing a field sort on the data array after Sy pointed out where I was missing the initial state: [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ThundarBeard/n87q75x9/1/)

Comment: One thing to mention is that would be good if you just set up a working jsfiddle with this code for quick tryouts.
On your problem: be sure that ´this´ means the correct object in your function, just log it in the click handler and see if it's a jquery callback function or your actual component.
Also, you have to initialize state with something.

Comment: Thanks. Sy's answer got me around the null issue. The code is truly spaghetti so I'm unravelling it. The jsfiddle point is well taken. I was hoping it would be obvious to the React all-stars. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`state` is `null` because you didn't set an initial value.

```
Test = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {};
  }
})
```

this is equivalent to

```
class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sy. This got me past the null reference error. This also pointed directly at where part of the sorting issue was also happening. I'm working through simplifying all of the code. I took the tact of sorting the data array manually. Working fiddle edited in the original question in case someone else is looking for this same answer.